# Construct StructType with StructField of a complex type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There is a type

```
case class RSSEntry(
  source: RSSFeed,
  uri: String,
  title: String,
  links: List[RSSLink],
  content: List[RSSContent],
  description: RSSContent,
  enclosures: List[RSSEnclosure],
  publishedDate: Long,
  updatedDate: Long,
  authors: List[RSSPerson],
  contributors: List[RSSPerson]
)
```

I use field `links`, field `title` and field `publishedDate`.

Here is the `RSSLink` type

```
case class RSSLink(href: String, title: String)
```

Now please see actual code below.

`val schema = new StructType()
        .add(StructField("title", StringType, true))
      spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD = newsInTrend, schema = schema)
        .show(20, false)`

`StructType` should consist of 3 fields: `title`, `links.href` and `publishedDate` as `String`. How do I construct the complex type of 3 fields?

**UPDATE**
Here is updated code.

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
    {
      val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(sc.appName).getOrCreate()
      import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
      case class RSSNews( title: String,
                          links: String,
                          publishedDate: String)
      val newsInTrend =
      rdd.toDF().select("links", "title", "publishedDate").rdd.filter(row =>
      {
        trends_.value.exists(word => row.getAs[String]("title").toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()))
      }).map(row => RSSNews(
                              row.getAs[String]("title"),
                              row.getAs[List[RSSLink]]("links").map(_.href).mkString(","),
                              new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-y").format(new Date(row.getAs[Long]("publishedDate")))
                           ))

      val structType: StructType = Encoders.product[RSSNews].schema

      spark.createDataFrame(newsInTrend, structType)
        .coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode(SaveMode.Append).save("D:/data/spark")//.show(20, false)
      val df1 = spark.read.format("json").load("D:/data/spark")
      df1.coalesce(1).write.format("json").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("D:/data/spark/subdir")*/
    })
```

Now I cannot create `DataFrame` with code `spark.createDataFrame(newsInTrend, structType)`, because `newsInTrend` is of type `RDD[RSSNews]`, not `RDD[Row]`.
Though there is `toDF` method, but compiler says I cannot call `toDF` on `newsInTrends`. I don't know why. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new case class from fields what you need, and take product.schema from it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

case class RSSLinks(title: String,
                    links: String,
                    publishedDate: String)

val structType: StructType = Encoders.product[RSSLinks].schema
val seqRSSEntries: Seq[RSSEntry] = ???
seqRSSEntries.map(rss => RSSLinks(rss.title, rss.links.map(_.href).mkString(","), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date(rss.publishedDate))))
```

**UPDATE:**

You can use RowFactory to create new Row from Array of objects:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, Row, RowFactory, SaveMode, SparkSession}

val newsInTrend: RDD[Row] = rdd.toDF()
  .select("links", "title", "publishedDate")
  .rdd.filter {
    row =>
      trends.exists(word => row.getAs[String]("title").toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()))
        }
  .map(
    row => 
      RowFactory.create(
        row.getAs[String]("title"),
        row.getAs[List[RSSLink]]("links").map(_.href).mkString(","),
        new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-y").format(new Date(row.getAs[Long]("publishedDate")))
      )
   )
```

Maybe creating RSSNews object is unnecessary.

Comment: How do you convert `publishedDate` to `String` in a date format? I know that it is an additional question, but still.

Comment: I edited answer. You can use SimpleDateFormat for that.